# Apache camel or Spring OutboundChannel

Tags: spring, ftp, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am currently working on a project which requires sending of files of moderate sizes to a server at a distant location using ftp. I've come across two methods to achieve it; Apache Camel and Spring FTP. I would like to know which of these two is better to use in my situation.

- I am sending confidential text files
- There is poor connectivity, but I need guaranteed delivery
- Server will probably be Amazon cloud

Also, is there some mechanism to distinguish between files which are received completely and partially at the server?

Comment: Reorganized information for clearer reading and some grammar corrections. Is "Spring OutboundChannel" the same thing as "Spring FTP"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Camel has a lot of out of the box functionality that would otherwise need to be developed in the spring application (using Spring FTP). Examples of this are error handling with re-delivery attempts and separate thread running.

With this, I would suggest to use Camel